# Run Where clause from another table in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I run where clause from another table?

For example:

### table1:

```
**sentence**
----------
AB      
AA      
AC      
AEF     
AHF
```

and but the where condition comes from another

### table 2

```
**text**
```

---

```
sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%B%'

sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%C%'

sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%E%' and sentence like '%F%'
```

I would like the result like this way:

**result**

---

```
AB
AC
AEF
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want dynamic SQL.  You cannot do this with a simple `select`.  You might want to re-visit your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need dynamic SQL.  I would suggest fixing your data model so this is not needed.  Instead of storing a `where` condition, I think you can use regular expressions instead:

- `'A.*B|B.*A'`
- `'A.*C|C.*A'`
- `'A.*E.*F|A.*F.*E|E.*A.*F|E.*F.*A|F.*A.*E|F.*E.*A'`

Note:  There are alternative ways to express the logic but I think this makes it clear.

Then you can do:

```
select t1.sentence, t2.pattern
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on regexp_contains(t1.sentence, t2,pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT text, sentence
FROM `project.dataset.table1`,
  `project.dataset.table2`, 
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, "'(.*?)'")) re
GROUP BY sentence, text
HAVING MIN(sentence LIKE re)
```

If to apply to data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 'AB' sentence UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AEF' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AHF' 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT "sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%B%'" text UNION ALL
  SELECT "sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%C%'" UNION ALL
  SELECT "sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%E%' and sentence like '%F%'" 
)
SELECT sentence, text
FROM `project.dataset.table1`,
  `project.dataset.table2`, 
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, "'(.*?)'")) re
GROUP BY sentence, text
HAVING MIN(sentence LIKE re)
```

result will be

```
Row sentence    text     
1   AB          sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%B%'  
2   AEF         sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%E%' and sentence like '%F%'  
3   AC          sentence like '%A%' and sentence like '%C%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join and concat  with proper logic condition

```
  select  table2.text
  from table2 
  inner join table1  on ( (table2.text like concat('%','A','%' )
                          and table2.text like concat('%','B','%' ) )
                      or ( table2.text like concat('%','A','%' )
                          and table2.text like concat('%','C','%' ) )  
                      or  ( table2.text like concat('%','A','%' )
                          and table2.text like concat('%','E','%' )
                          and  table2.text like concat('%','F','%' ))  )
```